# Webkit http support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http, webkit

I understand webkit allow web browsers to render web pages. So my HTML, CSS and java script code will run on any device which has webkit support. But what about http support. Does webkit has inbuild support for http communication?

Comment: As I understand it, there's a "default" HTTP stack available for WebKit, but as far as I know both Chrome and Safari use their own. Chrome's is open-source.

Comment: @EricLaw - you should make your response an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this will be helpful to other.

I downloaded webkit and ran sample ajax test and they were success

So answer to my question is yes, Webkit support http

Answer (score 0):

WebKit renders the content, I can't say whether it fetches content or not.

What I could find so far googling is that ResourceRequest, ResourceHandle, and ResourceResponse are classes that represent HTTP connections.

Comment: I want to know if webkit has HTTP support for it to make call to our backend server

Comment: Sorry, but if there is no support for HTTP in WebKit, I believe you could use curl or wget for what you want, and it should even work better.

Answer (score 0):

WebKit only manages the rendering and manages the HTTP Requests. When it however comes to accepting other forms of content such as images, jpeg, pdfs etc... WebKit does not handle those the Application developers have to handle that themselfs.

Source: Qt Development